# Sum using in dax command

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to do this expression but this shows an error:

```
vMotor_Paid =
CALCULATE (
    Paid_excel,
    SUM ( Paid_excel[PAID_AMOUNT] ),
    Paid_excel[Flag] = "Paid",
    Premium_Excel[LOB] = "MOTOR",
    Paid_excel[PAID_DATE] = { [VpeDate] }
)
```

Error:
`A function 'SUM' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.`

In the expression, I am trying to do SUM of `paid_amount` against filters of these

```
Paid_excel[Flag]="Paid",
Premium_Excel[LOB]="MOTOR",
Paid_excel[PAID_DATE]={[VpeDate]}
```

Here I create another variable of `VPeDate` where I fixed the date **"23-12-2017"**

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your date is wrapped in curly braces. I think you might have more luck like this:

```
vMotor_Paid =
VAR VpeDate = [VpeDate]
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Paid_excel[PAID_AMOUNT] ),
    Paid_excel[Flag] = "Paid",
    Premium_Excel[LOB] = "MOTOR",
    Paid_excel[PAID_DATE] = VpeDate
)
```

Now that `CALCULATE` filter is comparing versus a date rather than an expression that returns a date.

Comment: Good call. I had copied from the question and didn't look closely enough.

Comment: hi. thank for response... i am new to Dax command so i dont know whether we wrap date in curly braces or not .. . i try your expression and this return nothing check this image  https://www.dropbox.com/h?preview=motor.PNG

Comment: @AlexisOlson i found that when i remove this  Paid_excel[ PAID_DATE] = VpeDate then values i displayed but i want only  Motor in LOB and here all LOB is displayed sames goes for FLAG and why date is not working .. i store  date(2017,12,31) in VpeDate

Comment: and when i put this line " Paid_excel[ PAID_DATE] = VpeDate"  this shows an error .. A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
vMotor_Paid = CALCULATE(SUM(Paid_excel[PAID_AMOUNT]),FILTER(Paid_excel[Flag]="Paid"
,Premium_Excel[LOB]="MOTOR",Paid_excel[PAID_DATE]={[VpeDate]}))
```

Please check the calculate syntax

Comment: hello i store date in VpeDate like this "12-03-2017" and when i drag vmotor_paid in table this shows an error "Calculation error in measure 'Variables Table'[vMotor_Paid : DAX comparison operations do not support 
comparing values of type Date with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values "

Comment: hello @balaji ??